# Why does AngularFire $remove reload the controller?

Tags: angularjs, controller, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularfire

In an Angular app I have a table for 'Contacts', which is loading my Contacts from a FireBase database, using AngularFire. I'm trying to build in the UIBootstrap pagination directive (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination).

In the ContactsCtrl I set $scope.currentPage = 1; This is updated when clicked on a pagination link, all works fine. When I delete one of the Contacts with the following code (this happens in the Contacts service, btw) the ContactsCtrl reloads, the inital $scope.currentPage gets reset and I'm taking back to page 1 of my Contacts.

```
$firebase(new FIREBASE(url).$remove(contactId);
```

I'm not looking for a complete solution - but I'm trying to understand why $remove causes the controller to reload so to get a better understanding of Angular and FireBase. In the [AngularFire API docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html) I didn't find much help on this question.

Comment: I assume that the issue lies somewhere else. Could you set up a plunker with some more details?

Comment: Unrelated to AngularFire. You are probably clicking a link or submitting a form which is reloading the page. Try passing $event and calling preventDefault().

Comment: @Sprottenwels I've been creating the plunker and ofcourse, when done I found out the error didn't exist in my slimmed down version. Hunting down te actual error right now. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Found it. In case someone else stumbles upon the same question: I used a <a href="#" ng-click="function()"> tag - ofcourse I should not have included the href part.